# capturing ajax posted values in php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form that uses jquery form validation to change the email of a user. The problem that im having is when the user submits the values are posted but i cant capture it in my php file. It always prints empty

**Below is my code**

```
$("#change_email").validate({
    rules: {
        "new_email": {
            required:true,
            email: true
        },
        "confirm_email": {
            required: true,
            equalTo : "#email"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "new_email": {
            required: "required",
            email: "invalid"
        },
        "confirm_email": {
            required: "not match",

        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { 
        var formd = $(form).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/secular/change_email',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formd,
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("error");
            });
         return false;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="change_email">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">New Email :</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="new_email" id="email" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Confirm Email:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="confirm_email"  class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" type="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
function change_email()
{
    echo $email = $this->input->post('new_email');
}
```

When I check on firebug it posts as below

```
new_email=test%40test.com&confirm_email=test%40test.com
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Look here in Firebug, especially the response:

[image]

Comment: Do yourself a favor, simply place a `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` in the PHP page which receives the form submission. Fill out your form, submit and look closely at the data printed to the screen. Familiarize yourself with how form data is posted to scripts, including what gets passed and what doesn't.

Comment: i did that it shows an empty array

Comment: So you're not actually sending the data to the PHP, so `formd` is not populated which means serialize doesn't know what it is you're serializing.

Comment: but when i check in firebug in the post it shows `new_email=test%40test.com&confirm_email=test%40test.com` doesnt that mean the values are being passed? i even added the form id directly... but still the same.. :( Thanks

Comment: How in Firebug? Are you checking the request/response on the network tab?

Comment: on the console.. when i click. Its shows POST and the url. when i click in that link there is a tab called post

Comment: There should also be one called response

Comment: its empty when i echo and when i do a print or or var dump it gives me an empty array

Comment: The Response tab is empty? You do not have a submit button.

Comment: And look closely, you have a missing closing parentheses `}` in AJAX request. You closed the error function with a `}`, good. Now close the AJAX request with another `}`. By the way, as @JayBlanchard asked, how are you submitting the form? There's no submit button anywhere.

Comment: @JayBlanchard there is a submit button. i missed it when adding. edited now..

Comment: @RajdeepPaul when i add an extra parentheses it gives and error. I missed the submit button... added it to the code. Still the response is blank :(

Comment: @LiveEn Test your application with this script, [http://pastebin.com/euxAccC8](http://pastebin.com/euxAccC8).